# How do I access a cd drive using java?

Tags: java, windows, cd-rom

How can I access the CD Rom drive (in my case, F:) from Java? I don't mind platform specific code. I am using Windows 8. I have the following code but get AccessDenied.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {     
        File cd = new File( "f:\\lang" );
        System.out.println(cd.canRead());
        RandomAccessFile rawAccess = new RandomAccessFile( cd, "r" );

        rawAccess.close();
   }
```

The 3 trues are checking for cd.canRead, cd.canWrite, cd.canExecute.

```
   true
   true
   true
   Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: f:\lang (Access is denied) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source) at myapp.main(myapp.java:16)
```

Comment: Post the exception with message and stack trace.

Comment: So what's at `c:\Users\bzuil_000\bin` if you're actually trying to read `f:\lang`?

Comment: sorry, changed the code since the original post. Seems I can't access any directory including my user directory.

Comment: The output is the same for any existing file on my harddrive or cd-rom drive. If it is a UAC problem, I need help with the code to create a process with elevated priveleges. I attemted java myapp from a cmd terminal running as Administrator but it still produced the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see my error now. I'm trying to use the Java File object when what I really want is raw data from the disc. I was giving a directory and trying to open it like a file causing the error seen in the original post. It worked once I changed the path to a specific file.

I will create a new question that is more clear about what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`RandomAccessFile` provides access to Files not Directories.

The `FileNotFound` is thrown, because there is no file, just a directory.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile(java.io.File, java.lang.String)